# Update angular 8 to 10 using cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8, angular10, angular-upgrade

Using the ng update command to update the angular to the latest version. Keep getting the peer dependency issues.

I tried with the --force command, however, there were lots of different issues

```
                  Package "@angular-redux/form" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^6.0.0" (extended), would install "10.0.14").
                  Package "tsickle" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires "~3.8.2", would install "3.9.7")
                  Package "@angular-redux/form" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^6.0.0" (extended), would install "10.0.14").
                  Package "@angular-redux/form" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires "^6.0.0" (extended), would install "10.0.14").
                  Package "@angular-redux/form" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires "^6.0.0" (extended), would install "10.0.14").
                  Package "@swimlane/ngx-datatable" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "<9.0.0" (extended), would install "10.0.14").
                  Package "@angular-redux/router" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/router" (requires "^6.0.3" (extended), would install "10.0.14").
                  Package "tsickle" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires "~3.8.2", would install "3.9.7").


✖ Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "/private/var/folders/dh/r0v3cpq168x9bjxp1mjrrgxw0000gn/T/ng-nxMhiB/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Reference - https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out:
[Upgrade to Angular 9](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/upgrade-to-angular-9-within-10-minutes-671c6fd6174b?source=email-89975889a521-1598947985086-digest.reader------2-59------------------9ad910f1_b18e_406f_b1b4_0a698c4f2903-16-----)

You may follow this to upgrade from Angular 8 to 10 directly.

If that doesn’t work, upgrade to Angular 9 first, then use same strategy to upgrade from Angular 9 to 10.

And if that doesn’t work, I would say create brand new Angular 10 app and migrate components one by one. If it’s medium size app, it shouldn’t take more than 4 hours. This exercise will help you clean up some unnecessary code as well. Check this out:
[Upgrade from Angular 4 to 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60031213/2429586)

Hope this helps.